# Off the Shelf Current Sensors?

Tags: current, current-measurement, testbench

What are the tradeoffs between making my own current sense setup with a precision shunt resistor and ADC versus just buying something?  What are the most popular COTS current sensors for shunt current sensing?

Comment: High-side or low-side sensing? Current range? ADC range?

Comment: As you know, this is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum or an on-line technical encyclopaedia. This is a couple of lines that asks for mountains of effort in reply. Your second question is a shopping question and as such off-topic for the site and likely to be closed. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract.

Comment: With the ADC option, look over the major chip mfg's marketing literature. Search for "current sense applications". They will have various levels of integration, there may be a sweet spot that is right for you.

Comment: If you buy something you don't have to design anything. If you design something you can tailor the features to what you want and need instead of what the COTS vendor thought you might need.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, a purpose-built shunt interface will usually have a higher common-mode voltage tolerance, even beyond the supply of the interface IC.  Also, the 50 or 100mV full-current voltage of most shunt resistors could be a good deal lower than the minimum reference voltage input of your ADC.